# Nested STRUCT and UNION in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm, unions

I am trying to implement a c data structure in assembly language for a networking applicaton. NOTE: This is for an Assembly class project, so it needs to be in assembler!!!

Here is the c structure from MS docs:

```
typedef struct in_addr {
    union {
        struct {
          UCHAR s_b1;
          UCHAR s_b2;
          UCHAR s_b3;
          UCHAR s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
          USHORT s_w1;
          USHORT s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
        ULONG S_addr;
    } S_un;
} IN_ADDR, *PIN_ADDR, *LPIN_ADDR;
```

Here is the code in assembly language:

```
in_addr STRUCT
    UNION S_un
        S_un_b STRUCT      ; an error here!
            s_b1 BYTE ? 
            s_b2 BYTE ?
            s_b3 BYTE ?
            s_b4 BYTE ?    
        S_un_b ENDS        ; an error here!

        S_un_w STRUCT      ; an error here!
            s_w1 WORD ? 
            s_w2 WORD ? 
        S_un_w ENDS        ; an error here!

        S_addr DWORD ? ; the complete address
    ENDS
in_addr ENDS
```

When I try to build, I get an error message (see above comments) that is either a syntax error (in the first 3 cases) or an "unmatched block nesting" as the last one. I tried to look through Intel documentation on whether a struct can be defined within a union but I couldn't find any definitive information.

I will appreciate Intel / MS documentation as much as a solution, if not more. I am new to Assembly language, although it is becoming somewhat of a hobby, weirdly.

Comment: You probably have no reason to define this structure. Just use a DWORD to store IPv4 addresses directly. If you actually have some need to access the individual words or bytes that make up the 32-bit address then you can use something like `BYTE PTR [ipaddr + 3]` just like you would with any other DWORD value in memory.

Comment: @RossRidge If that is the case, that would simplify very nicely! Here is why I'm defining it though, please take a look and tell me if your suggestion still holds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-sendarp. Basically, I want to use the SendARP function, in which the DestIP and SrcIP are of type in_addr.

Comment: The `SendARP` function expects pointers to two `IPAddr` structures in memory, but structures and other types are just compile/assemble-time abstractions. If it expected pointers to two `DWORD` values in memory instead then the compiled code would be exactly the same, because it would access both with the same 32-bit instructions. Similarly you'll get same machine code generated from your assembly code whether you use a `in_addr` structure or a `DWORD`.

Comment: That should be the question I asked. @RossRidge thanks! Another similar question: I can just call SendARP from within an assembly program, or do I need to include some files? This is a separate question, I realize..

Comment: There isn't anything you can include. You'll need to declare with EXTERN and you may need to name it `_SendARP@16` because, like most Windows API functions, the 32-bit version uses the stdcall calling convention. You'll also have to link with `iphlpapi.lib`.

Comment: @RossRidge In general, how do I link with an external library? I'm a beginner and can't find any useful information online, at least that I can understand

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has a similar question, the way you define a union that contains structs would be to define the structs beforehand.

Here is what I had originally:

```
in_addr STRUCT
    UNION S_un
        S_un_b STRUCT      
            s_b1 BYTE ? 
            s_b2 BYTE ?
            s_b3 BYTE ?
            s_b4 BYTE ?    
        S_un_b ENDS        

        S_un_w STRUCT     
            s_w1 WORD ? 
            s_w2 WORD ? 
        S_un_w ENDS        

        S_addr DWORD ? ; the complete address
    ENDS
in_addr ENDS
```

That won't compile, at least in masm. Here is what can be done:

```
S_un_b STRUCT
    s_b1 BYTE ? 
    s_b2 BYTE ? 
    s_b3 BYTE ? 
    s_b4 BYTE ? 
S_un_b ENDS

S_un_w STRUCT
    s_w1 WORD ? 
    s_w2 WORD ? 
S_un_w ENDS

in_addr STRUCT
    UNION S_un
        S_un_b<>
        S_un_w<>
        S_addr DWORD ? ; the complete address
    ENDS
in_addr ENDS
```

To then use this structure, use regular struct operations:

For example:

```
; To set S_addr
mov <in_addr instance name>.<union_name>.S_addr, 0h
```

Similar priciples can be applied to access BYTEs and WORDs.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone with the same question.